# React navigation 5 tabBarBadgeStyle not working

Tags: android, ios, reactjs, react-native, react-navigation-v5

I am using `react-navigation-5` in my `react-native app`, I created a bottom tab using `@react-navigation/material-bottom-tabs`. I added a badge in one of the tab, i used `tabBarBadge` property for this and it is working fine. I need to change the badge `color` and `background colour`, for this I used `tabBarBadgeStyle` but it is not working,

```
<Tab.Screen         
  options={{
    tabBarBadge:88,
    tabBarBadgeStyle:{backgroundColor:'#fff'}
  }}
/>
```

Please help me to implement `tabBarBadgeStyle`

Answer (score 4):

https://reactnavigation.org/docs/themes/

```
const MyTheme = {
  ...DefaultTheme,
  colors: {
    ...DefaultTheme.colors,
    notification: 'red',
  },
}
```

and

```
<NavigationContainer theme={MyTheme}>
...
</NavigationContainer>
```

Comment: this is one of the methode but it is not working, is this working for you?